# Compile less file to css in expressjs 4.x

Tags: node.js, express, less

I want to compile the less file in public folder of expressjs application.

Dependencies which I am using are

```
"devDependencies": {
    "ejs": "^2.3.1",
    "express": "^4.10.6",
    "mysql": "^2.5.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "less": "^2.5.1",
    "less-middleware": "^2.0.1"
  }
```

Content in styles.less file

```
header {
    background-image: url('../img/bg.png');
    height: 380px;

    input#searchBox {
        width: 100%;
        height: 70px;
    }
}
```

Server file looks like below

```
var express = require('express'); // call express
var app = express(); // define our app using express
app.use(require('less-middleware')('public'));
// Public folder
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

The less file is not modified while running it on server.

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/css/styles.less
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
```

What is the error here.

Directory structure: [image]

Edit:

```css
header {
    background-image: url('../img/bg.png');
    height: 380px;
    #cloud-tag span {
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 800;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
    #cloud-tag_word_0 {
        font-size: 100px !important;
    }
}
```

I added this css in less file and it is being sent to browser in same format without being compiled.

Comment: What is your directory structure?

Comment: updated with structure of directory @sheldonk

Comment: Can you include the location of your nodejs code as well

Comment: nodejs code "server,js" is inside the root folder...i.e. sibling of node_modules folder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must request the css file, not the less file, in your case `http://localhost:3000/css/styles.css` not `http://localhost:3000/css/styles.less`.
The middleware will compile the less file to the one you requested.

Comment: it says Cannot GET /css/styles.css

Comment: I took your express code
`var express = require('express'); // call express
var app = express(); // define our app using express
app.use(require('less-middleware')('public'));
// Public folder
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(3000);
`

After that i created a directory public/css, in which i put style.less, now when i query `http://localhost:3000/css/styles.css` I get the compiled css...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the way you initilize the middleware to express might be the issue . Use "__dirname + '/public'" to denote the folder.